# Doubly linked list and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to figure out on how to make a doubly linked list work with polymorphism, but i have no clue :(
I'm trying to implement the classic example of animal and i have failed. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

// node class
template<typename T>
class nodeType
{
public:
  nodeType();
  nodeType(T);
  ~nodeType();

  nodeType *next;
  nodeType *previous;
  T data;
  string Id;
  void imprime();

  // getkey
  string getkey()
  {
    stringstream llave;
    llave << data.getkey();
    llave >> Id;
    return Id;
  }
};

// by defect
template<typename T>
nodeType<T>::nodeType()
{
  data = NULL;
  next = NULL;
  previous = NULL;
}

// by parameter
template<typename T>
nodeType<T>::nodeType(T data_)
{
  data = data_;
  next = NULL;
  previous = NULL;
}


// node printing
template<typename T>
void nodeType<T>::imprime()
{
  data.imprime();
}

template<typename T>
nodeType<T>::~nodeType() 
{
  delete next;
  delete previous;
}

// list

template <class T>
class list
{
private:
  nodeType<T> *first;
  nodeType<T> *last;
  nodeType<T> *current;
  int m_num_nodes;

public:
  list();
  ~list();

  void add_head(T);
  void add_end(T);
  void add_sort(T);
  //void fill();
  void search(string r);
  //void del_by_data(T);
  void del_by_data(int n);
  void print();
};

template<typename T>
list<T>::list()
{
  m_num_nodes = 0;
  first = NULL;
  last = NULL;
}

//add in the beginning ... 
template<typename T>
void list<T>::add_head(T data_)
{
  nodeType<T> *new_node = new nodeType<T>(data_);
  nodeType<T> *temp = first;

  if (!first)
  {
    first = new_node;
  }
  else
  {
    new_node->next = first;
    first = new_node;

    while (temp)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
  m_num_nodes++;
}

// add to the last
template<typename T>
void list<T>::add_end(T data_)
{
  nodeType<T> *new_node = new nodeType<T> (data_);
  nodeType<T> *temp = first;

  if (!first)
  {
    first = new_node;
  }
  else
  {
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new_node;
  }
  m_num_nodes++;
}

// it is supposed that sorts items in the list ...
template<typename T>
void list<T>::add_sort(T data_)
{
  nodeType<T> *new_node = new nodeType<T> (data_);
  nodeType<T> *temp = first;

  if (!first)
  {
    first = new_node;
    last = new_node;
  }
  else
  {
    if (first->getkey() > new_node->getkey())
    {

    new_node->next = first;
    first = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
    while ((temp->next != NULL) && (new_node->getkey() > temp->next->getkey()))
    {
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    // .. ¿? ..
    new_node->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = new_node;
    temp->previous = new_node->previous;
    new_node->previous = temp;
    temp->next = new_node;
    }
  }
  m_num_nodes++;
 }


// print list
template<typename T>
void list<T>::print()
{
  nodeType<T> *current;
  current = first;

  while (current != NULL)
  {
    current->imprime();
    current = current->next;
  }
}

// ............................................
template<typename T>
void list<T>::search(string r)
{
  bool found = false;
  current = first;

  while (current != NULL && !found)
  {
    if (current->getkey() == r)
    {
      found = true;
      current->imprime();
    }
    else
    {
      current = current->next;
    }
  }
  if (!found)
    cout << "Element not found\n";

}
// --------------------------------------------


template<typename T>
void list<T>::del_by_data(int n)
{

  nodeType<T> *temp = first;
  nodeType<T> *del;
  int i;
  bool deleted = false;

  if (n > 1 && n <= m_num_nodes)
  {
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
      temp=temp->next;
    }

    if (n == 1)
    {
      first = temp->next;
      temp->next->previous = NULL;
    }
    else if(n == m_num_nodes)
    {
      last = temp->previous;
      temp->previous->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      temp->previous->next = temp->next;
      temp->next->previous = temp->previous;
    }
  }
  m_num_nodes--;
}


// destroy the constructor
template<typename T>
list<T>::~list() {
  nodeType<T> *item;
  nodeType<T> *next;

  for(item=first; item != 0; item = next)
  {
    next = item->next;
    delete item;
  }
}

class animal
{
public:
   virtual void print()const 
   {  cout << "Unknown animal type.\n";
   }
   virtual ~animal(){} 

   string getkey()
   {
     string tipoanimal;
  }

  void imprime()
  {
    cout << "Ok" << endl;
  };

protected:
   int npatas;
   string tipoanimal;
};

//... Clase Ave ..
class ave: public animal
{
protected:
  string nombre;
  string nada;
  string tipo;
  string canta;
  string carroniero;

public:
   ave(int n, string c, string nom, string tip, string cant, string car,  string nad)
   {
     npatas = n; 
     tipoanimal = c; 
     nombre = nom;
     tipo = tip;
     canta = cant;
     carroniero = car;
     nada = nad;
  }

   void print()const
   { 
    cout << "Un " << nombre << " es un " << tipoanimal << " que tiene " << npatas 
     <<  " patas y es del tipo " << tipo << " " << canta <<  " canta y " << 
      carroniero << " es carroñero y " << nada << " nada" <<  endl;
   }
};


// mamifero
class mamifero : public animal
{
protected:
  string nombre;
  string tipo;
public:
  mamifero(int n, string c, string nom, string tip)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
  }

  void print() const
  {
    cout << "Un " << nombre << " es un " << tipoanimal << " que tiene " << npatas 
     <<  " patas y es del tipo " << tipo << endl;
  }
};

// Pez
class pez : public animal
{
protected:
  string nombre;
  string tipo;
  string nace;                                              // ovíparo,  vivíparo
public:
  pez(int n, string c, string nom, string tip, string nac)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
    nace =nac;
  }

  void print() const
  {
    cout << "Un " << nombre << " es un " << tipoanimal << " que tiene " << npatas 
     <<  " patas y es del tipo " << tipo << ", además es " << nace << endl;
  }
};


// reptil
class reptil : public animal
{
protected:
  string nombre;
  string tipo;
  string venenoso;
  string tamanio;

public:
  reptil(int n,  string c,  string nom,  string tip,  string ven, string tam)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
    venenoso = ven;
    tamanio = tam;
  }

  void print() const
  {
    cout << "Un " << nombre << " es un " << tipoanimal << " que tiene " << npatas <<  
      " patas y es del tipo " << tipo << " y " << venenoso << " venenoso, además es " << tamanio << endl;
  }
};

// ... Aves ..
class aguila : public ave
{
public:
aguila(int n, string c, string nom, string tip, string cant, string car,  string nad) 
    : ave(n,c,nom, tip, cant, car, nad)
  {
     npatas = n; 
     tipoanimal = c; 
     nombre = nom;
     tipo = tip;
     canta = cant;
     carroniero = car;
     nada = nad;
  }
};

class colibri : public ave
{
public:
colibri(int n,  string c,  string nom, string tip, string cant, string car, string nad) 
    : ave(n, c, nom, tip, cant, car, nad)
  {
    npatas = n; 
     tipoanimal = c; 
     nombre = nom;
     tipo = tip;
     canta = cant;
     carroniero = car;
     nada = nad;
  }
};

// ... Mamíferos ...
class gato :  public mamifero
{
public:
  gato(int n,  string c,  string nom,  string tip) : mamifero(n, c, nom,  tip)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
  }
};

class elefante :  public mamifero
{
public:
  elefante(int n,  string c,  string nom,  string tip) : mamifero(n, c, nom, tip)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
  }
};


// ... Peces ...
class beta : public pez
{
public:
  beta(int n, string c, string nom, string tip, string nac) : pez(n, c, nom, tip, nac)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
    nace = nac;
  }
};


class angel : public pez
{
public:
  angel(int n, string c, string nom, string tip, string nac) : pez(n, c, nom, tip, nac)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
    nace = nac;
  }
};

// ... reptil ...
class lagartija : public reptil
{
public:
  lagartija(int n, string c, string nom, string tip, string ven, string tam) 
    : reptil(n, c, nom, tip, ven, tam)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
    venenoso =ven;
    tamanio = tam;
  }
};

class tortuga : public reptil
{
public:
  tortuga(int n, string c, string nom,  string tip, string ven, string tam) 
    : reptil(n, c, nom, tip, ven, tam)
  {
    npatas = n;
    tipoanimal = c;
    nombre = nom;
    tipo = tip;
  }
};

// ... imprime ...
void Imprime(animal animal)
{
  animal.print();
}

// +++++++++++++++++++++++++
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++
int main()
{
  list<animal> * list1 = new list<animal>();

  string element1;
  string element2;

  // ......
  int count = 10;
  //animal* p[count];
  ave* b[count];
  mamifero* m[count];
  pez* pp[count];
  reptil* r[count];
  int i, j ;
  // ......

  int dim, choice, pos;
  dim = 0;

  do{
    cout << "Select a choice.\n";
    cout << "1. Print list\n";
    cout << "2. Delete an element of the list\n";
    cout << "3. Search an element of the list\n";
    cout << "4. Exit\n";
    cout << "Option: ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1:
      {
    cout << "Printing list:\n";
    cout << "Se van a añadir los siguientes elementos:\n";
    cout << "Animal: Ave. Patas: 2,  Tipo: aguila, alimento:carnivora," 
         << "Canta: no, Carroñero: no, Nada:no\n";

    // ... agrega elementos a la lista ...
    list1->add_sort(new ave(2,"ave","aguila", "carnívoro", "no", "no", "no"));
    list1->print();
    cout<<endl;
    break;
      }

      case 2:
      {
    dim++;
    if (dim == 1)
    {
      cout << "Element to delete: \n";
      list1->del_by_data(1);
      element1 = "";
      cout << endl;
      list1->print();
      cout << endl;
      cout << "\nElement deleted\n";
      cout<<endl;
    }
    if (dim == 2)
    {
      cout << "Element to delete: \n";
      list1->del_by_data(4);
      cout << endl;
      list1->print();
      cout << endl;
      cout << "\nElement deleted\n";
      cout << endl;
      dim = 0;
    }
    break;
      }

      case 3:
      {
    dim++;
    if (dim == 1)
    {
      cout << "Element to search: \n";
      list1->search("");
      element1 = "";
      cout << endl;
      list1->print();

      cout << endl;
    }
    if(dim == 2)
    {
      cout << "Element to search: \n";
      list1->search("");
      element1 = "";
      cout << endl;
      list1->print();

      cout << endl;
      dim = 0;
    }
    break;
      }
    }
  }while(choice != 4);
  return 0;
}
```

When i try to compile the code, this error appears:
error: no matching function for call to ‘list::add_sort(ave*)’
    list1->add_sort(new ave(2,"ave","aguila", "carnívoro", "no", "no", "no"));

Any can explain me what does this error means and how to fix it?? (o.O) (?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that's the only error you get

Comment: If you're using GCC / Clang, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Weffc++`, fix the errors / warnings you can, and repost your question. There's a lot of very basic mistakes in your code that can be trivially detected by the compiler.

Comment: Regarding your error, plain and simple you're dynamically allocating an object that needs no such allocation. Simply using something like `list1->add_sort(ave(2,"ave","aguila", "carnívoro", "no", "no", "no"));` will send a temporary to your list. And I would advise you look at your use of references, or lack thereof, in places such as the `add_sort` parameter list. As it sits now this will [**object-slice**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/274634#274634), which is rarely intentional (and this is no such case where it would be so).